# Snap Shot of Links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, link-only-answers, hyperlinks, external-links

Some links may in cause of time disappear and become invalid. Hence it would be good to have a mechanism to crawl the old links in the site and also have a snapshot of the link. For new posts the snap shot can be added when the link was added to the post. This way validity of a post is not lost in case the references / additional information disappear.

Comment: Excellent idea. Who's gonna pay for all the bandwidth and storage required to achieve this? And while we're at it, what about the copyright issues?

Comment: The main problem is as content ages many of the links in old posts will become invalid. We cannot run away from the fact that there are many questions which do have link in SE and SO sites. Storage is becoming cheaper now. One the links are cached then only links relating to new posts need to be cached. This can also be compressed.

Comment: If not what are the alternate ways this can be handled for older content which might end up having broken links? As mentioned above links supplement a question or answer. The quality of the user experience deteriorates when this supplementary information goes missing.

Comment: Two words: Wayback Machine.

Comment: I also wonder if you can just mirror pages copyright-wise...

Comment: Google does it. You can look at a cached snapshot of a page. Web archives sites also does it.

Comment: I don't think wayback machine accurately captures many of the blogs and other personal site links especially without static content.

Comment: I cannot believe this question only has 1 upvote. FYI some question on meta: [Archiving links referenced in questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228702/178179)

Comment: It would be great if some of the bibliographic references can be capture especially in SE sites in which such references matter.

Answer (score 9):

This is exactly why the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) says this about answers:

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, **in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline**.

It is also one of the reasons users can edit answers. To fix links if they break.

Besides, in my personal opinion, this is far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: All is good if this is strictly the case. What about all the content which is already there which does have links and there is substantial value in being able to see what is in the link. Going by this stance is OK if all the content is fully curated and strictly adheres to this in all SE / SO sites.

Comment: I'm interested in this: is fixing broken links with archive.org mirrors too minor especially when there isn't enough context given? I've done so before and been heavily rejected each time however I see value in it.

Comment: Having access to the entire linked page may be more convenient than having access to only some quoted part